# how to turn off zookeeper log info?

Tags: c, logging, apache-zookeeper

I am using zookeeper c client library. When I run my program, it will output ZOO_INFO to console. Part of log messages looks like:

> 2015-03-26 20:08:22,115:15978(0x7f83a1fbc740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@712: Client environment:zookeeper.version=zookeeper C client 3.4.6
>
> 2015-03-26 20:08:22,115:15978(0x7f83a1fbc740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@716: Client environment:host.name=myhost
>
> 2015-03-26 20:08:22,115:15978(0x7f83a1fbc740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@723: Client environment:os.name=Linux
>
> 2015-03-26 20:08:22,115:15978(0x7f83a1fbc740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@724: Client environment:os.arch=3.2.0-34-generic
>
> 2015-03-26 20:08:22,115:15978(0x7f83a1fbc740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@725: Client environment:os.version=#53-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 10:48:16 UTC 2012
>
> 2015-03-26 20:08:22,115:15978(0x7f83a1fbc740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@733: Client environment:user.name=myname
>
> **...**

I can use **zoo_set_log_stream(m_zklog);** to output these messages to some log files. But I prefer to turn off all the log messages. I also tried **zoo_set_debug_level( ZOO_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR );**. But it can not turn off all the messages.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use C API zoo_set_debug_level() (e.g. `zoo_set_debug_level((ZooLogLevel)0)`). But call this function before zookeeper_init(), otherwise, it will fail.

Comment: the only valid arguments are following :

`# only used by the C extension
   ZOO_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR = 1
   ZOO_LOG_LEVEL_WARN  = 2
   ZOO_LOG_LEVEL_INFO  = 3
   ZOO_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG = 4`

Comment: @serup, could you give more details? I used the function long ago.... But it works.

Comment: I tried without parameters on a ubuntu 16.04lts build and it would not compile - so perhaps things have changed - I ended up using this instead : 
`zoo_set_log_stream(fopen("NULL", "w"));`

Comment: @serup My answer was a little confusing. `Use zoo_set_debug_level()` means `zoo_set_debug_level(<parameters>)`, e.g. `zoo_set_debug_level((ZooLogLevel)0)`. The point of my answer was that the function should be called before zookeeper_init(), otherwise it cannot work. My answer updated. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: what is (ZooLogLevel)0  if it does not result in one of the valid arguments, then it will fail

Comment: @serup, I just gave an example that zoo_set_debug_level() has input parameter. We are using clients of different version. Just add the parameter according to your doc. The above example works fine in our codes, and I did not give all contexts, which are not important to my points.

Answer (score 1):

```
FILE* outfile =  fopen ("nul", "w");
  zoo_set_log_stream(outfile);
```

Comment: this is windows on linux you can use /dev/null

Comment: you could write something like this :

zoo_set_log_stream(fopen("NULL", "w"));

Comment: `if (!m_zkLogFile)
   {
      zoo_set_debug_level( (ZooLogLevel)0);
#ifdef WIN32_OS
      m_zkLogFile = fopen ("nul", "w");
#else
      m_zkLogFile = fopen ("/dev/null", "w");
#endif
      zoo_set_log_stream(m_zkLogFile);
   }` This works ...